# Converting a string into an equation

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to convert a String into a equation using ScriptEngine.
My code asks for a linear equation and a value for X.  After that it replaces x for the value. 
When i try to add "*" after "()" it doesn't work and thus it doesn't evaluate the string equation

```
package known;

import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.util.stream.DoubleStream.concat;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

/**
 *
 * @author netof
 */
public class Known {

    /**3
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {



        System.out.println("Insert your equation");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String equation = sc.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("Insert value for X");
        String x = sc.nextLine();



        System.out.println();

       String test = equation.replace("x","("+x+")");



        if(test.contains("("+x+")")){

            String replace = test.replace("("+")", "*");

            System.out.println(replace);

        }else{
            System.out.println("Can't Replace");
        }

}
   ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String convert = replace;
System.out.println(engine.eval(replace));
}
```

Comment: 1. This code doesn't compile (`replace` is undefined, `System.out.println` outside of a method). 2. It's unclear what is the expected and actual output (and for what input). http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What if the user enters "z" as the unknown?  What if there's more than one unknown?  Not a good concept.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to have the x as int instead of String?

int x = sc.nextIn();

Or you can parse the String x as int

String x = sc.nextLine();
int xx = Integer.parseInt(x);

Just couple of suggestions.